# At least one of $4$ integers is $0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, quadratics

I encountered this very interesting problem in my work and it sounds like this:

> Let $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$ca-3bd=5$$ $$ad+bc=2$$
>   Prove that at least one of them is $0$.

I tried (using the idea that a perfect square is non-negative) to multiply with $d$ the first relation and then with $c$ the second, and then first with $c$ the first relation and then with $d$ the second and by adding/subtracting I obtained $$a(c^2+3d^2)=5c+6d$$ $$b(c^2+3d^2)=2c-5d$$ but it doesn't help much. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: This is saying $(a+b\sqrt{-3})(c+d\sqrt{-3})=2+5\sqrt{-3}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yeap.

Comment: You can make it stronger by saying that only one of them is zero

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $w=a+b\sqrt{-3}$ and $z=c+d\sqrt{-3}$, this is saying $wz=5+2\sqrt{-3}.$

Then $|w|^2|z|^2=\left|5+2\sqrt{-3}\right|^2=37.$

But $|w|^2=a^2+3b^2, |z|^2=c^2+3d^2.$

So you actually get that either $|w|^2=1$ or $|z^2|=1$, and hence that either $(a,b)=(\pm 1,0)$ or $(c,d)=(\pm 1,0).$

---

If you don't want to use complex numbers, then you can prove directly that:

$$(a^2+3b^2)(c^2+3d^2)=(ac-3bd)^2+3(ad+bc)^2$$

Comment: Very nice! Thanks.

Comment: I don’t think your $wz$ is calculated right.

Comment: I'd need specifics, @razvanelda

Comment: can’t write right now, it is 5+2sqrt...

Comment: Oops, yes. Funny, I wrote $5+2\sqrt{-3}$ first, then "corrected" myself.

Comment: Yea I get it no problem :)))

Answer (score 1):

Write first equation (you got) like this $$ac^2-5c+(3ad^2-6d)=0$$
since this quadratic equation on $c$ must have a solution we have $D\geq 0$ so

$$ -12a^2d^2 +24ad +25\geq 0$$
write $x=ad\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $$ 12x^2-24x-25\leq 0$$
so
$$ 12 (x-1)^2= 12x^2-24x+12\leq 37$$ so $(x-1)^2\leq 3$ so $|x-1|\leq 1$ so $x\in \{0,1,2\}$.

$\bullet$ If $x=0$ so $ad =0$ and we are done.

$\bullet$ If $x=1$ then $a=d=1$ or $a=d=-1$ then...

$\bullet$ If $x=2$ then $bc=0$ and we are done.